# Synergy 1.4.17 breaks holding down two modifier keys in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, synergy, modifier-keys

In Synergy 1.4.16 you can hold down two modifier keys (e.g., <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>) simultaneously.

In 1.4.17 the second modifier key supersedes the first,
so if you hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>,
it releases <kbd>Command</kbd>.

This is verified using the keyboard viewer from system preferences.

Is this a known bug?  Is there a work-around; i.e., a way to get two modifier keys to be in effect simultaneously?

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue.  Best example is that I can't take screen captures (<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>4</kbd>). Have you figured out a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Synergy team fixed this problem in Synergy 1.4.18

As of this posting, 1.4.18, is not available as stable release yet, but can be found in the [Nightly Builds](http://synergy-foss.org/nightly/) section

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and just upgraded to 1.5.0: I can use multiple modifiers once again!